# How to parse KML file using angularjs to take cooordinates for plygon

Tags: angularjs, kml

I have polygon KML file, I want to parse it in angularjs 1 to extract the coordinates of each point of polygon.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? Have you tried something yourself? Are you stuck with this? Have you tried searching the Internet for an answer?

Comment: @Sjoerd I tried even to understand the structure of polygon KML file. there is no much doc about that

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the angularJS parsing code, but I can tell you about the structure of the KML file.

Inside the KML, you should find one or more `<Placemark...>` tags, each representing one polygon or group of polygons. Each `<Placemark>` will contain either a `<Polygon>` tag, or a `<MultiGeometry>` tag with multiple `<Polygon>` or other geometry tags inside it.

Inside each `<Polygon>` tag, you will find a `<coordinates>` tag. That is where all the points (vertices) which make up the polygon are found. They are listed as either "`longitude,latitude`" pairs, or "`longitude,latitude,altitude`" triplets. The numbers inside each pair or triplet are separated by commas, and the pair or triplets themselves are each separated by a space. Note that in KML the coordinates are listed in the order: longitude,latitude (x,y), which is opposite of most other places.

You can find full documentation on the structure of KML in the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference). Hopefully that gives you enough to figure out how to parse out the points.

Comment: thank youfor the answer what about other tags outerBoundaryIs,  LinearRing, innerBoundaryIs. because these tags contains the coordinates tag I need and I want to know how to parse it. are these tags required in KML file?

Comment: Yes, some of those tags are required. Have you read the KML Reference? A basic, bare-minimum polygon will have this structure: 

<Polygon>
  <outerBoundaryIs>
    <LinearRing>
      <coordinates>...</coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
  </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>